# How to show a child window on its parent?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple sample;I have 2 window in may sample such as ParentWin & ChildWin
In  my ParentWin i have a button like this

```
<Button Name="button1" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
   private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChildWin childwindow = new ChildWin();
        ChildWin .ShowInTaskbar = false;
        childwindow.ShowDialog();
    }
```

When my ChildWin Is in ShowDialog mod if I select ParentWin it actived and my ChildWin Hide. 
I want that when I select ParentWin from TaskBar my ChildWin does not Hide **like a MessageBox Dialog**;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must set the owner window in parent window like this :

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChildWin childwindow = new ChildWin();
        childwindow.Owner = this;
        ChildWin.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        childwindow.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I knlow this is too late  but may help someone else   . . .

There is simple way to show a window on parent window in .net:

Just select child window form >

go to property window

and turn "Topmost" property to true.
now this window will appear on top of all other windows . .that's all . . ..